# Question about the condition of a while loop regarding a particular example

Tags: c++, function, while-loop, conditional-statements

This function is supposed to add one string to another:

```
char* myStrCat(char* str1, const char* str2)
{
int i, j = 0;
for (i = 0; str1[i]; i++);

while(str1[i + j] = str2[j])
{
    j++;
}

return str1;
}
```

Which works perfectly fine however, I do not understand why this while condition gives us the wanted output. As far as I know, the loop will be repeated, as long as the condition holds. Why does this condition hold in the first place?

Comment: Note that it's an assignment, not a compare. It terminates when a zero char is seen.

Comment: The value of `str1[i + j] = str2[j]` is just the value of the right hand side i.e. `str2[j]`. So the loop terminates when `str2[j] == '\0'`.

Comment: it doesnt "work perfectly fine". depending on sizes of `str1` and `str2` this is an out-of-bounds access: `str1[i + j]`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: there are "just" pre-requirements of the function.

Comment: @Jarod42 if a function is never called, it also "works perfectly" ;). I get your point, anyhow the crux seems to be just `=` vs `==`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: issue is with (C) signature ([strcat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat)). template (to know size of buffer), `std::string` would be type safe, using extra variable `size`, might allow to check, but requires extra parameter which also should be correct. (but indeed OP problem is understanding result of assignation in condition).

Comment: I got it thank you - the misunderstanding was indeed between "=" and "=="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because in C++ the assignment operator "returns" the assigned value, to enable statements such as

```
i=j=1
```

Therefore `str1[i + j] = str2[j]` evaluates to the value of `str2[j]`. And because it written as the condition of the while loop it will be converted to `bool` (from `char`). The conversion rule is: zero becomes `false`, everything else becomes `true`. Therefore it loop until reaching the terminating zero character of `str2`.